# How to find a point along a line a certain distance away from another point, but in R^3?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have seen many posts about 2 dimensional planes, but how will this work in 3D? Obviously the equation for the line changes so the original "formula" can no longer work. Any ideas?

Comment: The title doesn’t really match the question. Do you have a point and a line? Where does a plane come in.

Comment: If the distance in question is  $ \ D \ $ , write the equation of a sphere with radius  $ \ D  \ $  centered on the point. The point(s) on the line that are a distance $ \ D \ $  from the reference point are the intersection(s) of the line with the sphere (so you also need the equation in  $ \ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ for the line).  [There are even on-line calculators that will do this for you...]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the line is a defined by a point $A$ that lies on it, and a unit vector $B$ giving it’s direction.

If $P$ is some point on the line, then the points of the line that are a given distance $d$ away from $P$ are $P \pm dB$.